Manipulating QGIS Tools via PyQGIS
It is necessary to write a script for PyQGIS that would open the "DWG/DXF Import" module, fill in the input and source data for it, and then perform the operation.
This piece of code will be inserted into a loop that iterates through the folders in which the DWG files are stored, resaving them in the gpkg format.
I know that this can be implemented using QT, but after several hours of study, I still have not found a solution.
In fact, if you know a solution to the problem of mass resaving of DWG data in the gpkg or DXF format, then this would be preferable. I do not offer options with Aspose.CAD and ODA Converter, for one reason or another they did not work.

Not possible with pyqgis API. Duplicate question, QGIS enhancement request
